# Can this answer be regarded as spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892277/issues-with-responsive-design-email-template-css-and-inline-styles-conflicting) the user has asked about some inline [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) issues he is having with his responsive HTML email template and a specific problem that the [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) desktop client doesn't respect the `display:none;` property and so on.

Now, [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892277/issues-with-responsive-design-email-template-css-and-inline-styles-conflicting/24821429#24821429) just gives the URL to their website that provides a service for making responsive email templates.

It seems like a promotional link to me, that doesn't provide a solution to the question's specific problem, and I did mark it as spam, but the flag got denied.

So I am putting it up here for discussion: can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892277/issues-with-responsive-design-email-template-css-and-inline-styles-conflicting/24821429#24821429) regarded as spam or not?

Comment: Looks like a spam answer by an [account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3721164/email-chopper) solely created to post spam...

Comment: That is *basolutely* spam. If your flag was denied then *someone done make a mis-take*; e.g. human error.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Of course it is spam. That the product is very tangentially relevant to the question doesn't make it a good answer.

Did you not see the username and his profile?

I have destroyed the account as a spammer account.

Comment: Another post for same site here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/19395202/124259

Comment: @oded: ya did see the account name and so I flagged it , may be because of just some human error it got denied , so quickly posted it here.Thanks for the fast response, I guess I will have to wait another 7 minutes to accept it . :)